# django-haystack with elastic search not building index for newly add index model

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I'm using Haystack 2.3.1 and trying to figure out multiple indexes.

I've got elasticsearch cores set up and defined each in HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS, and
then I've created three SearchIndexes in search_indexes.py.

When I run the command manage.py rebuild_index, I see this warning.

Thanks for any tips and let me know if I'm missing anything.

setting.py:

```

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'default',
    'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    'SILENTLY_FAIL': True,
    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['dmmactress.search_indexes.ActressInfoIndex'],
},

'autocomplete': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'autocomplete',
    'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    'SILENTLY_FAIL': True,
    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['dmmactress.search_indexes.EnActress'],
},

'autocomplete2': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'autocomplete2',
    'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    'SILENTLY_FAIL': True,
    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['dmmactress.search_indexes.EnMovielist'],
},
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

```

search_indexes.py

```

```
class ActressInfoIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    birth = indexes.CharField(model_attr='birth')
    starsign = indexes.CharField(model_attr='starsign')
    bloodtype = indexes.CharField(model_attr='bloodtype')
    boobs = indexes.CharField(model_attr='boobs')
    home = indexes.CharField(model_attr='home')
    hobby = indexes.CharField(model_attr='hobby')
    image_paths = indexes.CharField(model_attr='image_paths')

    def get_model(self):
        return ActressInfo

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()


class EnActress(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    image_paths = indexes.CharField(model_attr='image_paths')

    def get_model(self):
        return EnActress

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()


class EnMovielist(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    Content_ID = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Content_ID')
    release_date = indexes.CharField(model_attr='release_date')
    running_time = indexes.CharField(model_attr='running_time')
    Actress = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Actress')
    Series = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Series')
    Studio = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Studio')
    Director = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Director')
    Label = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Label')
    image_paths = indexes.CharField(model_attr='image_paths')

    def get_model(self):
        return EnMovielist

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

```

_text.txt

```

```
{{ object.name}}
{{ object.image_paths }}
{{ object.birth }}
{{ object.starsign }}
{{ object.bloodtype }}
{{ object.boobs }}
{{ object.home }}
{{ object.hobby }}


{{ object.EnMovielist.Content_ID }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.image_paths }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.release_date }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.running_time }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.Actress }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.Series }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.Studio }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.Director }}
{{ object.EnMovielist.Label }}



{{ object.EnActress.name}}
{{ object.EnActress.image_paths }}
```

```

..after running

`Indexing 9464 actress infos
GET /autocomplete/_mapping [status:404 request:0.001s]
Indexing 9464 actress infos
GET /autocomplete2/_mapping [status:404 request:0.003s]`

Comment: Why have you defined three backends that are identical? It doesn't make sense to define multiple backends pointing to the same Elasticsearch cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that which version of `elasticsearch` you are using? If you are using `django-haystack` then your `elasticsearch` should be less than 2.00.